# How do I upload an image from my application to my nodejs server?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upload an image from my android client onto my node js server. On the client side I capture the image using callbacks which gives me a byte[], which I then save into my internal storage before posting the path to my server (is this a recommended approach?).

- I have successfully uploaded the entire image as a buffer but I cannot get the streams to work.

I have a byte[] file which I have saved internally

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(image);
        fos.close();
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + FILENAME);
        path = file.toString();
```

and then using a socket.io connection, I emit the path of the file to my server

```
socket.emit("upload_image", _id, path);
```

On the server side I listen for the emit and try to save the image file into my database (mongodb) using the module gridjs

```
socket.on('upload_image', function (_id, img) {

var gs = gridjs(db);

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(img).pipe(gs.createWriteStream('test-file'));
readStream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("caught: ", err);
});
readStream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
readStream.on('open', function () {
});}
```

The server responds to the emit from the client, but an error is thrown when trying to create the read stream

```
Error: ENOENT, open '/data/data/com.example.myapplication/files/image-2015-05-31_17-04-59.png'
```

I am not sure if the path I have is correct, or if Im using createReadStream incorrectly. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ENOENT **e**rror means there's **no ent**ry in the file system for the specified file, i.e. file doesn't exist.

Comment: `posting the path to my server`}. That probably makes no sense. As what should the server do with that path? Just store in a database and waiting for the same client to retrieve that path? You probably want to upload the bytes of an image instead.

Comment: You guys are right, thank you. I was able to successfully upload my image as a buffer and saving it using write() instead of createReadStream().pipe

Comment: The reason I was trying to use the createReadStream was to add metadata at the time of the upload but instead I ended up querying the uploaded file and updating the metadata